# Does a FIFO data buffer need to have the data be registered?

Tags: verilog, shift-register, buffer, data, fifo

I'm trying to implement a 64 bit FIFO Data Buffer in Verilog.  My design allows for data to be written at 4 bytes or 1 byte at a time, and I'm simply using two multiplexers with control signals for determining which mode it is writing to a memory array.  Before the data is written to the memory array, does it need to be passed into a register or can it just be directly inputted into the memory array at wherever the write point is currently?

Comment: https://scialert.net/fulltext/?doi=jas.2015.576.581 Learn how to use DMA https://learn-cf.ni.com/teach/riodevguide/code/fpga-pc_dma-fifo.html

Answer (score 1):

In FIFO implementations it's always the read(capture) & write(launch) pointers that need to be registered.

Refer this [link](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2002SJ_FIFO1.pdf)